# nodejs run custom script before main script

Tags: node.js

I want to run `../my_dir/my_script.js` each time when I run `node index.js` from actual app project folder.

In others words, I need `my_script.js` to be common in every app (A,B,C...N) and executing before `index.js`

Structure:

```
+my_dir
  -my_script.js
+appA
  +node_modules
  -package.json
  -index.js
+appB
  +node_modules
  -package.json
  -index.js
```

my_script.js

```
console.log('my_script.js from parent directory STARTED');
```

package.json (similar for each appA, appB ... etc)

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    //I HAVE TRIED
    "start": "node ../my_dir/my_script.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run-script ../my_dir/my_script.js",
    "preinstall": "npm run --prefix ../my_dir/my_script.js",
    
  }
}
```

index.js (similar for each appA, appB ... etc);

```
console.log('index.js STARTED');
```

If I try inside appA `node index.js` I got `index.js STARTED`

If I try inside appA `npm start` I got `my_script.js from parent directory STARTED`

Expected: (running both):

```
my_script.js from parent directory STARTED
index.js STARTED
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to automatically have a second script run when using the command line `node` command.
What you can do is either run both scripts manually

```
node ../my_dir/my_script.js && node index.js
```

or bundle them in your package.json

```
"start": "node ../my_dir/my_script.js && node index.js",
```

and execute with

```
npm start
```

Your `postinstall` and `preinstall` are not quite right, those get run when doing `npm install` (you can put the `post` and `pre` keywords before any command https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts)

so you could also do

```
"start": "node index.js",
"prestart": "node  ../my_dir/my_script.js"
```

and execute with

```
npm start
```

again

Comment: Tested now `"start": "node index.js",
"prestart": "node  ../my_dir/my_script.js"`  with `npm start` AND IT WORK! Thank you